# React storybook not reloading on changes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook

I have a react application I created with `create-react-app` and I have added storybook to it. When I run `yarn run storybook` it does not reload when I change files.

My application is laid out like

```
src
->components
--->aComponent.js
->stories
--->index.js
->index.js
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "immutable": "^3.8.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.3.14",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^3.3.14",
    "@storybook/addons": "^3.3.14",
    "@storybook/react": "^3.3.14",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.67.1"
  }
}
```

I have no custom web pack config. What do I need to do to get hot module reloading working?

Answer (score 4):

You must increase your watch count

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

Comment: Is `524288` a magic number, or is there some kind of logic behind that value?

Comment: It's 2^19. But probably just a large enough "round" number.

Comment: I wish this had fixed it for me!! :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, should pass `module` as a 2nd argument for `storiesOf`

```js
                   // V Won't hot reload with `module`
storiesOf('Welcome', module).add('to Storybook', () => <Welcome showApp={linkTo('Button')} />);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too,
my environment  was:

```
ubuntu 18.04  
"react": "^16.10.1",  
"react-dom": "^16.10.1",  
"react-scripts": "3.1.2",  
"@storybook/react": "^5.2.1"
```

I solved this problem with running as the sudo user like this:

```
sudo yarn run storybook
```